# Phonegap geolocation plugin is not adding for android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

[Geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

I am trying to get geolocation details , i have added  geolocation plugin using cordova command line

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation
```

Application created using cordova commandline

[The Command-Line Interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

After adding plugin through command line android plugin is missing

in the following screenshot android is missing 
[image]

Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: Did you add Android as a plugin?

Comment: Did you try actually using the plugin on a page and see if there are errors? The native code was removed so you won't see an "Android" folder, but you still need to add the plugin so that it will add the correct permissions into AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 10):

The native code for Android Geolocation was removed, see the [deprecation bug.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977) This was because the native implementation was buggy and the native browser geolocation works fine. Since Cordova (Phonegap)'s goal is to not exist, it was only a matter of time until this was removed. You can use Geolocation just like you normally would, it just won't use the native code and instead rely on the browser version.

If you look in the plugin xml file, you will see that there is still some lines in there about Android. This is so that `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation` will correctly copy in the needed permissions to run on Android.

Comment: As an aside, there are some JavaScript only plugins out there, and if you added on of these, you would expect the same thing - a "missing" folder inside /myApp/plugins/foo/ - since there is no native code. If you look in /myApp/plugins/foo/www/ you will see the relevant JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link : [Go to Add Plugin Features](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

**Add Plugin Features**

You can use the CLI to search for plugins from this registry.

For example, searching for *geolocation*  produces a single result that matches  terms as case-insensitive :
Just search for plugin in command prompt.

```
cordova plugin search geolocation
```

By firing above command you will get search result as :

```
org.apache.cordova.geolocation - Cordova Geolocation Plugin
```

Now to install this plugin you need to fire :

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

You will get result as :

```
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.geolocation" via plugin registry
Installing "org.apache.cordova.geolocation" for android
```

Finally, the geolocation plugin will be installed in your application_name/plugins directory.

Path will look as : *D:\PhoneGap\hello\plugins\org.apache.cordova.geolocation*

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to make you happy.It took a whole day for me to sort out this.
Better you downgrade the version of geolocation plugin. Go through below steps:

a)Remove the already downloaded geolocation plugin:
phonegap plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation

b)Add the downgraded geolocation plugin:
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation@0.3.2

Now you will see the android folder under the plugins folder.
Cheer up!!